# How can I know from where is installed my app?

Tags: flutter, google-play, app-store, testflight, google-developers-console

I want to know from where is installed my app from app store or test flight, from google play users or internal testers.

I tried use store_check package but it doesn't help.
I don't find the solution for that.
Is there other way to know it in Flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 possibilities:

- Create 2 flavors: one for production release on AppStore/PlayStore and a second for beta release on TestFlight &/or others.
- You can also use this plugin to know store provider easilly without creating flavors: https://pub.dev/packages/install_referrer

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package to provide the path and all data about your app in flutter application
here is an example for use :
https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider/example

Answer (score 0):

Implement two app configurations:

**Production:** This configuration is intended for the final, publicly available version of the app, deployed on the App Store and Play Store.
**Beta:** This configuration is designed for the beta testing phase, allowing a select group of users to access and provide feedback on the app before its official release. Utilize TestFlight or other beta testing platforms for distributing the beta version.
Leverage the install_referrer plugin to effortlessly identify the app store provider without the need for additional flavors. This plugin simplifies the process of determining the source of app installation, whether it's the App Store, Play Store, or another platform.
[ILT20](https://theilt20.com/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).